# All of my wordpress sites showing †Ù¥

Tags: errors, encoding

This morning I was going to keep working on my Wordpress page, then when I put in the domain name it only showed this: †Ù¥

I then checked my other sites who I hadn't touched in a while and they also showed this error. I contacted the hosting provider but they don't know what the problem is since the wordpress sites on other accounts work just fine. When I do a fresh install it's alright but all the existing sites show these characters. I think it's a database error. Other sites hosted on my account which do not use wordpress do not have this problem.

My question is, how do I resolve this?

An example of a site I have running on wordpress but displays:
http://jntvnetwork.com/

Hoping for the best!

Best regards,
Steve

Comment: Hello Steve,

Please check your `.htaccess` file, maybe some attacker forward your requests to any other HTML file with that weird characters. If your .htaccess file is ok , try deactivating all plugins and activating one of the WordPress default themes. If problem is gone after these steps, try enabling plugins one by one so you can catch the plugin which causing this error.

Comment: Hi Eray,
Thanks for the reply. I can't access my wordpress account through wp-admin and my htaccess file seems to be alright. I have 4 wordpress sites and they're all displaying this so it's not a plugin since I don't have the same plugins on all the sites. This is really weird.

Comment: It's weird that characters disappering when you refresh page. So it's about sessions which can be a security vulnerability. I recommend you to **backing up all files&database** , deactivate all plugins and themes and update manually by following this guide : https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Somehow your files get broken.  It can be UTF8 encoding problem,  hacker attack,  broken plugin. It's difficult to say what happend without checking your files and log.  Delete all unused plugins and themes from your WP installation.  Now I'll send an answer so you can choose it as accepted answer  :)

Comment: Well I did this, worked for a few hours then down again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your files get broken. It can be UTF8 encoding problem, hacker attack, broken plugin. It's difficult to say what happend without checking your files and log.

I recommend you to **backing up all files&database** , 
deactivate all plugins and themes and update manually by following this guide : codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update

Answer (score 0):

Immediately Take backup of the root files from your Hosting panel and Upload fresh WordPress files, it will fix the issue. Its not a Database Issue Rather a New Hack came which is making sites corrupt.

There is not changes in .htaccess and other thing. Instead of spending time on hit and trial please follow what I advice, Just coming from recovering a Dozen of sites.

After you that Please set File permission of your .htaccess file "404" then index.php "400" config file "400" blog-header file "400"

Please make your site live first then update me I will give you more tips.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem at 2 of my clients websites.
The problem in both cases was in the page.php situated in the theme file.

What I did? First; made sure WordPress was fresher up by reinstalling manually.
Then removed the malicious code from the page.php file and voila!Works like a charm! Hope this helps!